# How to access WAMP virtual host address from docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wamp, devops

After searching I have found below address to connect with WAMP address **http://localhost** from docker container.

```
host.docker.internal
```

Now I want to connect my virtual hosts address **http://ebwp.test** from docker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue